# SignalR Messages delivering twice for Angular nested components

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I have a strange situation where Signalr messages are being delivered twice for nested components (**undesired**), but only once for routed components.

Firstly, I have a generic method in my SignalR service:

```
...

recieve<T>(topic: string, callback: (d: T) => void): void {
  this.connection.on(topic, (d: T) => {
    callback(d);
  });
}
```

I have a notification component that gets **nested** and re-used wherever I want it. This component "subscribes" to the SignalR service method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    onNotification<IOrder>(callback: (d: any) => void): void {
        this._signalRService.recieve("some_topic", (notification) => {
          // Receive notification
        });
      }
}
```

Now when routing back and forth between components that re-use the notification component, the `onNotification` method gets triggered twice. When no routing has been done, the nested component will only receive the message once thus only triggering `onNotification` once.

This is not the case for routed components i.e with router-outlets.
Even though the routed and nested component's are re-constructed on each route that takes place you would think that the routed component would also get the notification twice, but only the nested component does.

To solve the issue, I had to [remove the handler from the specific hub method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1e108de5127276f376452e9de4d10a34ba677228/src/SignalR/clients/ts/signalr/src/HubConnection.ts#L499) in the nested component's `ngOnDestroy`:

```
removeHandler(topic: string): void {
  this.connection.off(topic);
}
```

So why would the nested component's messages be delivered twice?